# Maximum BackStack size in android

Tags: android, back-stack, java-memory-model

I'm a new one to android development. I need to know the **Maximum memory Size** of **BackStack** in *android*
And i want to know How many **activities** of **Android Application** can be **stored in BackStack**

Thanks

Comment: Bad news: It'll depend on the device's resources. Everything else can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Hope that keeps you from drawing false conclusions.

Comment: This question sounds suspiciously like a "I have a problem, but I'm attacking a symptom" question.  What, exactly, is happening that causes you concern about the size of the back stack?

Comment: An android app should run on all android devices with out any crash & memory problems. Memory problems should be considered before developing an application, So i asked

Comment: Fair enough.  I just wanted to make sure that your actual question was being answered.  Sometimes, people focus on an aspect of an issue rather than the actual underlying issue, so it pays to be safe and be thorough.  It's a worthy goal to address memory considerations, but with hundreds of types of Android devices, not an easy one to attain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum memory size of your back stack is the same as the amount of free memory on your device.  You can keep throwing things on the activity stack until you get an OutOfMemoryException. 
 Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/MvQ_rctYq2I)